# Angular Date Filter's format section not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter, angular-filters, datefilter

I want to show date with format '`MM/dd/yyyy`'.
 The date filter working but that format of date part doesn't working.

the following one is my code:

```
this.$filter('date')(this.BeginDate, 'MM/dd/yyyy')
```

Comment: Is `BeginDate` definitely a `DateTime` object?

Comment: @phuzi `BeginDate` can also be a string or a timestamp

Comment: @svarog true, it could be a string but it would have to formatted as a datetime that JS would be able to interpret as a datetime. If it's a `DateTime` object or a timestamp then there is no ambuiguity.

Comment: just stating what's in the docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a quick example of what you need, check the way you call the filter in your controller

```js
angular.module('myApp',[])
.run(function($rootScope,$filter){

  $rootScope.date = $filter('date')(new Date(),'MM/dd/yyyy'); // the issue is here
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  {{date}}
</div>
```